# Does "defined by cases" only work for decidable sets or also for semi-decidable sets?

Tags: computability, decidability

If $A,B\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ are disjoint decidable sets then it is clear to me that the function $f$ is defined as:

$f\left(x\right)=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if }x\in A\\
2 & \text{if }x\in B\\
\text{undefined} & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

is partial recursive.

This can be proved on base of the fact that
the characteristic functions of $A$ and $B$ are total recursive
functions.

Now I wondered:

> What if $A$ and $B$ are not decidable but semi-decidable?

Intuitively I thought of procedures $a$ and $b$ that
would eventually confirm (by halting) for $x\in\mathbb{N}$ that $x\in A$
and $x\in B$ respectively.

Letting them work side-by-side on input $x$ the following things can happen:

- $a$ halts and we conclude that $f\left(x\right)=1$
- $b$ halts and we conclude that $f\left(x\right)=2$
- Both do not halt so that $f\left(x\right)$ stays undefined.

However I failed to make this formal by means of functions
or codes of functions.

My questions are:

> - Is $f$ partial recursive if $A$ and $B$ are both semi-decidable?
> - If so then how to prove it formally?
> - If not then what is wrong with my intuition?

Thank you for taking notice of this question and sorry if it turns out to be a duplicate.

Comment: This is true. For formal proof - what definition of semi-decidable sets you use?

Comment: @mihaild In my context a set is semi-decidable by definition if it can be recognized as the domain of a partial recursive function.

Answer (score 2):

A partial function $f$ is partial recursive if there is a computational process, $F$ say, (e.g., a Turing Machine) that given an input $x$ to $f$ will always terminate if $x$ is in the domain of $f$ and, if that is so, $F$ will give the right value of $f(x)$.

In your case, you know that the two sets $A$ and $B$ are disjoint and semi-decidable. That means that there are computational processes $a$ and $b$ such that given an input $x \in A$, $a$ will terminate and $b$ will not and such that given an input $x \in B$, $b$ will terminate and $a$ will not. (Given an input that is not in $A \cup B$, both $a$ and $b$ will fail to terminate.)

Now you can come up with the desired computational process $F$: given an input $x$, $F$ should interleave a run of $a$ and a run of $b$ on input $x$. If $x \in A \cup B$, then exactly one of these runs will terminate and will tell $F$ whether $x$ is in $A$ or $B$. If $x \not\in A \cup B$, then $F$ will never terminate - and that is fine given our requirements on $F$.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer confirms my intuition. However my main aim is a formalization. It might be that in your conception your answer *is* a formalization, but I work in a context of partial recursive functions (defined as the smallest class of functions that contains primitive recursive functions and is closed under composition and $\mu$-minimalisation). Functions are shown to be partial recursive by defining them by means of other partial recursive functions or codes of them. Computational processes only come in to show more or less that a function is a candidate for being partial recursive.

Comment: I was deliberately using the vague term "computational process" because I didn't know whether you were working with Turing Machines as your notion of computational process. In your context, you will need to figure out a way of interleaving two computations: I think you will need to use $\mu$ to pick the code of the first $a$ and $b$ that produces a result.

Comment: Thank you for inspiration. I have added an answer myself. I would appreciate it if you checked this answer, but do not feel obliged to do so.

Comment: Your answer looks good to me.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by the comment of Rob Arthan I found this solution myself.

---

Let $G(x)$ and $H(x)$ denote the functions prescribed by:

$G\left(x\right)=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if }x\in A\\
\text{undefined} & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

$H\left(x\right)=\begin{cases}
2 & \text{if }x\in B\\
\text{undefined} & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

Then both functions are partially recursive hence have codes.

Let $g$ be a code for $G$ and let $h$ be a code for $H$.

If $T(e,x,t)$ stands for Kleene's primitive recursive predicate for functions with domain $\mathbb N$ and $U$ is the primitive recursive function that provides the output of a computation $t$ we have:$$f(x)\simeq U(\mu t.[T(g,x,t)\vee T(h,x,t)])$$

From this it can be concluded that $f$ is a partial recursive function.